# How can I create 360° Videos?

Tags: video

First I don't want make an animation. I just want to understand how I can make a Scene and wander around in it with 360°.

I mean [this as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaVQP351NYA).

Comment: um... parent the camera to an empty, and animate the empty to rotate 360°?

Comment: He means 360° video, you can pan around in his example.

Comment: X-27 gave you the answer, just don't animate it. I think X-27 should officially write the answer, so you can give the credit where it is due, but until that happens, do these basic steps: Shift+S >> Cursor to Center, Shift+A >> Empty >> Plain Axis, Select the Camera, Shift + Select The Empty, Ctrl + P >> Object, Hit A to deselect All, Select The Empty, Hit Numpad 0, Hit R, Hit Z, Then move your mouse.

Comment: @poor and Jerryno, Polosson, ARadish & ,stacker, I think, he asked something different than in the question you marked as a duplicate - have you had a look at his example video?

Comment: @Samoth Let's wait for the OP - consider that your edit is not confirmed yet. In general more effort would be nice, then I will vote to reopen with pleasure ;)

Answer (score 2):

In blender cycles, change your camera settings to these[image: 360 camera settings]

Then render and use KolorEyes to run your 360 video: http://www.kolor.com/kolor-eyes/

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great App [VRAIS](http://vrais.io/) which uses Blender and they provide a [tutorial](http://vrais.io/tutorial) of how to render stereoscopic panoramas for this App:

> - Render dimension: 2048x1024 for starters, and for final rendering 4096x2048 (just type in 200% in the render percentage).
> - In the Render Layers Panel, enable "Views"
> - Set your camera to Panoramic. Choose "Equirectangular" from the dropdown menu
> - Enable "spherical stereo" (Only available in Dalai's version)
> - set the pivot point to „Center“

Or you could watch some not so static [360° Videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzuqhhs6NWbgTzMuM09WKDQ). Pedro Gaspar made a [tutorial](http://pedrogaspar.weebly.com/blog/making-a-360-video-on-blender-to-be-published-on-youtube) of how to create them in Blender. Blenderrendersky already [created some videos](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/04/01/more-360-bge-footage/) in the BGE with this method.