# How to Create Photo Collage Template using Blender?

Tags: image, video, blend-files

I want to create a photo collage template in Blender. Is there any template available for this already?

My requirements is to create a video that covers several photos. Those photos should be pasted on the wall like a motion poster. Like photo collage apps for Android.

Here is the [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWRByQ1KfOs) sample for what I want as a Blender template. It is a corridor with videos along the walls and a studio at the end. I would like to create it and include my own vids.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48174/2843

Comment: There is no template available. You could ask Pedro if he could provide you his Scene or you have to rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUzyteaGlqU&nohtml5=False

Comment: @Samoth exactly i want one like this video. Thanks and i will try to implement it

Comment: I gave this a down vote as the question is against the intent of stack exchange. The OP is essentially asking for a do-everything button by posing a very broad question.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build the entire scene, that video link it's 360° and has a blog post link in the description that explains how to do it. It's that a requirement for you? (think twice because it involves much more work)

Second if you want just the camera movement try the [Sniper addon](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/569-addon-sniper-camera-automation.html)

Comment: Yes I want to do 360 video , before that i decided to model photo collage. and that link dosnot have proper step for Beginners Learners